# IBM MQ Explorer

Tags: ibm-mq

I have installed IBM MQ Explorer 9.1.5.0 in my new Laptop and trying to Add Remote Queue Manager by entering these details

- Host Name => localhost
- port => 1414
- server-conn-channel => SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN

But getting this error:

Could not establish a connection to the queue manager - **reason 2538**. (AMQ4059)
Explanation: The attempt to connect to the queue manager failed. This could be because the
queue manager is incorrectly configured to allow a connection from this system, or the
connection has been broken.

I am getting MQRC 2538 and I have tried with my firewall off and still getting this error. Any Suggestions will be very helpful.

Comment: Can you telnet to localhost:1414?

Comment: Implemented it earlier and now also( telnet localhost 1414) but getting Connection Failed. Could you please suggest what to do in this case.

Comment: Where is the queue manager that you are trying to connect to? Is it also on your new laptop?

Comment: No @MoragHughson. I am trying to first time create the new Queue Manager so that I can create Queues under that and can use in my IIB App.

Comment: I understood what you are trying to ask but in that case how to create the Queue Manager for the first time in my system in order to connect to that Queue Manager.

Comment: If you are using localhost then that implies that MQ is installed on your laptop. Could tell us the process you followed to install MQ on your laptop?

Comment: I downloaded the ZIP file for IBM MQ Explorer 9.1. Unzipped it and installed the setup in C drive and nothing else. The installation steps includes simple standard steps.

Comment: Do you have mq software installed and a queue manager created and configured on a different host?

Comment: I have to create the Queue Manager for the first time in order to use it in ACE. But I am getting this error while creating it for the first time in IBM MQ Explorer.

Comment: No @JoshMc. I am doing everything on the same machine.

Comment: IBM MQ Explorer 9.1 is just a tool to connect to a queue manager.   You would need the MQ software installed and a queue manager created to have anything to connect to.

Comment: I understood @JoshMc. Thank you so much for the meticulous reply. Sorry I got confused with the whole thing earlier.